# Second derivative of binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, derivatives

I try to prove that according to binomial distribution $P(X=k)={n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ the maximum probability $P(X=k)$ is achieved at maximum likelihood, i.e. $p=\frac{k}{n}$.

Let's apply $\log$ and take the first derivative.

$$\log P(X=k) = \log {n \choose k}+k \log p+ (n-k)\log (1-p)$$

$$\frac{d \log P(X=k)}{dp} = \frac{k}{p}-\frac{n-k}{1-p}=0 \quad \iff \quad  p=\frac{k}{n}$$

The problem is to show that what I found is indeed the global maximum, i.e. I need to show that the second derivative is negative everywhere.

I would appreciate if someone could help me with the second derivative.

The second derivative

$$\frac{d(\frac{k}{p}-\frac{n-k}{1-p}) }{dp} = -\frac{k}{p^2}-\frac{n-k}{(1-p)^2}$$

it's negative because $n>k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}=-\frac{1}{x^2} <0$

Comment: Thank you for your hint, I've added to the question, please, take a look.

Comment: You don't need to go past the second step: it's clear that since $n>k>0$ the whole expression is always negative

Comment: Oh, thank you, I missed it.

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear why you want (or need) to take the logarithm before 
taking the derivative.
The function $g(p) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ has value $0$ at $p=0$ and $p=1$
and is positive for $p \in (0,1)$. The product rule for differentiation gives
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dg(p)}{\mathrm dp} &= \left.\left.\binom{n}{k}
\right[kp^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k} - p^k(n-k)(1-p)^{n-k-1}\right]\\
&= \binom{n}{k}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k-1}\left[k(1-p) - p(n-k)\right]\\
&= \binom{n}{k}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k-1}\left[k- np\right]
\end{align}$$
which is $0$ only at $p = \frac{k}{n} \in (0,1)$. Can you see why
it is possible to deduce that $g(p)$
has a maximum (and not a minimum or inflexion point)
at $\frac{k}{n}$ without needing to take the second derivative and applying the second derivative test?

Comment: In many stats courses students are taught to take logs before finding MLE estimates. In this specific case this simplifies things a bit.